# Switching over multiple enums

Tags: swift, enums, protocols

The context for this is that I have a protocol which covers a very general case of what I want to do. And then I conform two other sub-protocols to it.

```
protocol MasterProtocol {}

protocol ChildProtocol1: MasterProtocol {}
protocol ChildProtocol2: MasterProtocol {}

class Thing1: ChildProtocol1 {}
class Thing2: ChildProtocol1 {}

class Thing3: ChildProtocol2 {}
class Thing4: ChildProtocol2 {}
```

Now I have an enum setup like this

```
enum Protocol1Classes {
    case thing1
    case thing2
}

enum Protocol2Classes {
    case thing3
    case thing4
}
```

Now I have two very closely related enums where the combined cases cover all the classes that conform to the MasterProtocol and I want to switch over their combined values

```
func doThing(value: (Protocol1Classes || Protocol2Classes)) {
    switch value {
    case .thing1:
        // Do Master Protocol Stuff to Thing1
    case .thing2:
        // Do Master Protocol Stuff to Thing2
    case .thing3:
        // Do Master Protocol Stuff to Thing3
    case .thing4:
        // Do Master Protocol Stuff to Thing4  
    }
}
```

Clearly this wont work. Is there a way to get something like this? Without having to declare a third enum which just combines the cases in the two enums?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need 2 enums in the first place if each case corresponds to a very specific class? And if you want to do "Master Protocol Stuff" then why does the type of the object matter?

Comment: I use the 2 enums to selectively pull classes from either of the enum lists should I need to do something related to their protocols directly to them from a 3rd semi-unrelated class. But occasionally, I need to do something to potentially any of the classes based on a shared variable that they all carry from the master protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily solve this by implementing the same function for both enums and then the compiler will know which one to use.

```
func doThing(value: Protocol1Classes) {
    switch value {
    case .thing1:
        print("do stuff 1")
    case .thing2:
        print("do stuff 2")
    }
}

func doThing(value: Protocol2Classes) {
    switch value {
    case .thing3:
        print("do stuff 3")
    case .thing4:
        print("do stuff 4")
    }
}
```

Then calling them will be simple

```
doThing(value: .thing1)
doThing(value: .thing2)
doThing(value: .thing3)
doThing(value: .thing4)
```

> do stuff 1
> do stuff 2
> do stuff 3
> do stuff 4